# Display webpage in the Page View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have two own blogs, I am trying to create a application using the PageViewController. Where the first and second page should display their respective blogs. I am ok with the ViewControllers, but I don't where to get started for the Page View Controller , Can any one provide any tutorial or sample for the Page View Controller ?

Comment: [Apple already had.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313)

Comment: @H2CO3 . I knew that, You can see that I have mentioned that in question too. I found little difficult and confused after reading the doc. Thats why I asked for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

This may help you.

Comment: This is what Exactly I want to do. Thanks